# glMapBufferRange freezing OpenGL driver

Tags: c++, opengl, crash, timeout, driver

After generating a set of data using a compute shader and storing it in a Shader Storage buffer, I am attempting to read from that buffer to print out the data using the code:

```
#define INDEX_AT(x,y,z,i)   (xyzToId(Vec3i((x), (y), (z)),\
                                     Vec3i(NUM_RAYS_X,\
                                           NUM_RAYS_Y,\
                                           POINTS_ON_RAY))\
                             * 3 + (i))
PRINT_GL_ERRORS();
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, dPositionBuffer);
float* data_ptr = NULL;
for (int ray_i = 0; ray_i < POINTS_ON_RAY; ray_i++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < NUM_RAYS_Y; y++)
    {
        int x = 0;
        data_ptr = NULL;
        data_ptr = (float*)glMapBufferRange(
            GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,
            INDEX_AT(x, y, ray_i, 0) * sizeof(float),
            3 * (NUM_RAYS_X) * sizeof(float),
            GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
        if (data_ptr == NULL)
        {
            PRINT_GL_ERRORS();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_RAYS_X; x++)
            {
                std::cout << "("
                    << data_ptr[x * 3 + 0] << ","
                    << data_ptr[x * 3 + 1] << ","
                    << data_ptr[x * 3 + 2] << ") , ";
            }
        }

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
        PRINT_GL_ERRORS();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
}
```

where the function xyzToId converts three dimensional coordinates into a one-dimensional index.

When I attempt to run this, however, the program crashes at the call to glMapBufferRange, giving the error message:

```
The NVIDIA OpenGL driver lost connection with the display driver due to exceeding the Windows Time-Out limit and is unable to continue.
The application must close.

Error code: 7
Would you like to visit
http://nvidia.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/nvidia.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=3007
for help?
```

The buffer that I am mapping is not very large at all, only 768 floats, and previous calls to glMapBuffer on a different shader storage buffer (of only two floats) completed with no problems. I can't seem to find any information relevant to this error online, and everything that I have read about the speed of glMapBufferRange indicates that a buffer of this size should only take on the order of tens of milliseconds to map, not the two second timeout that the program is crashing on.

Am I missing something about how glMapBufferRange should be used?

Comment: "*Am I missing something about how glMapBufferRange should be used?*" Yes. You should not map a buffer *in a loop*. This is a heavy-weight operation; it is not merely returning a pointer. You should unmap it only when you are *finished* reading from the range of storage. Never map a few bytes. That may or may not fix your problem, but regardless, it is the wrong way to work.

Comment: The problem is that, while the buffer is not very large in this particular application (which I am using to debug the code on a smaller data-set), the intended usage involves a buffer too large to fit in the memory that I have available. Breaking it in to smaller pieces was the only way to avoid that problem.

Regardless of the above, I tested it with glMapBuffer, using the entire buffer all at once, and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: "*a buffer too large to fit in the memory that I have available*" Then how do you allocate such a buffer? If it's too big to map, then it's too big for `glBufferData`. Furthermore, that still doesn't justify mapping a few floats at a time. If you can't map the whole range, then map *large* parts of the range.

Comment: OpenGL buffers reside in the GPU's memory, not the CPU's RAM. They are, however, mapped into RAM. I'm mapping a few floats at a time here just to test the system. Doing one row of the data set at a time is small, here, but in the final system would be large enough to sufficiently use up my budget of memory.

Comment: "*OpenGL buffers reside in the GPU's memory, not the CPU's RAM.*" Untrue. Buffers reside in GPU-*accessible* memory. That may be actual video RAM or it may be CPU RAM that is set up for the GPU to access (across the PCIe bus, for example). Implementations tend to move buffers around based on how you use them. In most implementations, if you map a buffer, that buffer will be in CPU RAM. Also, most computers have more CPU memory than GPU memory, so even if what you said was true, I fail to see how you could allocate a buffer so large that it could not be copied to CPU memory.

Comment: "Also, most computers have more CPU memory than GPU memory, so even if what you said was true, I fail to see how you could allocate a buffer so large that it could not be copied to CPU memory." When I say "The memory I have available" or "my budget of memory" when referring to CPU memory, nothing about that communicates that I have the entire swath of RAM for my use. This code comes from a library which will, at some point, hopefully, become a single part of a very much larger application. I have a very restricted amount of CPU resources to use, but have a graphics card all to my self.

Comment: (contd.) Thus, I can get away with using _maybe_ a GB of RAM at the most, but have a full 16 GB of GPU memory to swim around in. In response to "I fail to see how you could allocate a buffer so large that it could not be copied to CPU memory." I'm not sure if you're asking how I could generate that much data, to which all I can say (without getting super-duper-fired) is very easily, thank you. If you're asking how I could generate a buffer via glBufferData large enough that it couldn't be mapped, then ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. I guess that kind of gets to another aspect of my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an unrelated error. Today I learned that OpenGL sometimes buffers commands, and several actions (like mapping a buffer) forces it to finish all the commands in its queue. In this case, it was the action of actually dispatching the compute shader itself.

Today I also learned that indexing a shader storage buffer out of bounds will cause the OpenGL driver to freeze up just like it would if it was taking to long to complete.

All in all, this was largely a case of errors masquerading as different errors and popping up in the wrong spot.